# How to put \SI in a yticklabel?

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx, ticks

How can I get my pgfplot to let siunitx write labels on the form `\SI{10}{\milli\metre}`?

The following does not work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    yticklabel={\SI{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}{\milli\metre}}
  ]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've also tried `yticklabel={\SI{\tick}{\milli\metre}}`, which prints e.g. "10.000 000 000 mm", but I'll admit that the spacing is correct.

Is my only option to do `yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick} \si{\milli\metre}}` and try to set the spacing between number and unit manually?

Comment: Probably of topic, but in `siunitx` version 3 is `\SI` is obsolete. Instead it rather use `\qty` for values and `\unit` for units .

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for letting me now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue is that you want to round the result: the fact that `\tick` has rather a lot of decimal places is perhaps odd but it *is* what the value for the axis is. You can round without needing to use v3 features

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    yticklabel={\SI[round-mode = places]{\tick}{\milli\metre}}
  ]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

although I would hope you have v3 and can use the more semantic `\qty` here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realise `\SI` was deprecated, I've now read the entry in the new manual about the replacements for `\SIlist`, `\SIrange` and `\si`.

Comment: Hi Joseph, out of curiosity (and to convince my colleagues to switch to `\qty`), will the support of `\SI` be dropped altogether in the near future? Or will it always be kept for backward compatibility?